# Error with Auto variable in a function C++

Tags: c++, function, auto

I'm having problems on passing a value between functions in C++. I add the code below. In mqttReceive, a MQTT message in JSON is received and it is sent again in send() to be received in void send(). However, I've tried to declare the received message as auto, but it doesn't work. What I'm missing?

cpp:

```
void MqttApplication::mqttReceive()
{
    try {
        
        mqttClient->start_consuming();
        mqttClient->subscribe(TOPIC, QOS)->wait();
        
    }
    catch (const mqtt::exception& exc) {
        cerr << exc.what() << endl;
        return;
    }

    
    while (true) {
        auto msg = mqttClient->consume_message();   
        

        try {               
            send(msg);
        }
        catch (const mqtt::exception& exc) {
            cerr << exc.what() << endl;
            return;
        }

        if (msg->get_topic() == "command" &&
                msg->to_string() == "exit") {
            cout << "Exit command received" << endl;
            break;
        }

        cout << msg->get_topic() << ": " << msg->to_string() << endl;
    }
}



void MqttApplication::send(auto msg)
{
    ...
}
```

hpp:

```
class MqttApplication : public Application
    {
    private:    
    
        void send(const auto msg);
    
        void mqttReceive();
```

The error:

```
In file included from /home/mqtt_application.cpp:1:
/home/mqtt_application.hpp:26:24: warning: use of ‘auto’ in parameter declaration only available with ‘-fconcepts-ts’
   26 |     void send(const auto& msg) override;
      |                        ^~~~
/home/mqtt_application.hpp:26:35: error: member template ‘void MqttApplication::send(const auto:1&)’ may not have virt-specifiers
   26 |     void send(const auto& msg) override;
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~
/home/mqtt_application.cpp:320:34: warning: use of ‘auto’ in parameter declaration only available with ‘-fconcepts-ts’
  320 | void MqttApplication::send(auto& msg)
      |                                  ^~~~
/home/mqtt_application.cpp:320:6: error: no declaration matches ‘void MqttApplication::send(auto:2&)’
  320 | void MqttApplication::send(auto& msg)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/mqtt_application.cpp:1:
/home/mqtt_application.hpp:26:10: note: candidate is: ‘template<class auto:1> void MqttApplication::send(const auto:1&)’
   26 |     void send(const auto& msg) override;
      |          ^~~~~~~
In file included from /home/mqtt_application.cpp:1:
/home/mqtt_application.hpp:15:7: note: ‘class MqttApplication’ defined here
   15 | class MqttApplication : public Application
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tools/mqtt.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'tools/mqtt.dir/mqtt_application.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [tools/mqtt.dir/mqtt_application.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:834: recipe for target 'tools/mqtt.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/mqtt.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm compiling with C++14. I've tried all kind of configurations, string, int, etc. The input is a regular JSON string. Thanks

Comment: The compiler needs to know the exact type of `msg`.

Comment: Auto is not a correct type for msg?

Comment: @thecoder, `auto` isn't a type. It's a placeholder that works in specific contexts to tell the compiler to deduce the type.

Comment: Try thinking of auto more like an alias, in the cpp file the compiler can deduce the returned type from `mqttClient->consume_message()` and so is happy just calling that auto. However in the hpp when defining the function signature for `::send(...)` the compiler has nothing to go on. If you want send to be generic you could consider templating `send` other wise you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Using `auto` as a parameter is a [C++20 feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function), some compilers support it as extensions in earlier versions but its not ISO there.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax for function templates requires C++20. For C++17 and older, you need to change this:

```
void MqttApplication::send(auto msg)
```

to:

```
template <typename T>
void MqttApplication::send(T msg)
```

Both are equivalent, but the C++20 version is shorter. See [Abbreviated function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template).

Comment: I could declare auto variables using C++11 but I cannot pass as an argument with this version? I mean, I just need to pass the auto msg to the send function.

Comment: @thecoder You need to pass `msg` to a function that can accept the type of `msg`. `auto` is not a type, so you can't have a function that accepts `auto` as some form of type. You need a function template for this, or a function that accepts an `std::any`. Always keep in mind that C++ is a statically typed language. All types are deducted at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what you expected to happen? With "auto" in a function declaration, the compiler cannot know what the type is so it refuses to compile. That's different from "auto x = 3; " where the compiler knows the type of x should be the same as the type of 3.

If your compiler understands concepts and you understand concepts then you can make your code build, but that requires you understanding a major brand new C++ feature.

Comment: No concepts involved here though. `void f(auto)` is just a normal template. `void f(Some_Concept auto)` would involve concepts.